# Set up end of this week, next of this month and end of next month dates

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to set up a few variables to then pass into my code to add some classes. I know how to do most of it, but it's the setting of the variables that's difficult.

I need to set up three variables that will be compared with the current date.

```
<?php $current_date = date('Ymd'); ?>
```

The three variables are: **this week**, **this month** and **next month**.

I had originally set my **this week** variable as so:

```
<?php $current_date_week = date('Ymd', strtotime($current_date . ' +7 days')); ?>
```

But I'm getting this wrong. It shouldn't be from today's date + 7, it should get the date of the **end of the current week** using the `Ymd` date format. So if today's date is **20140326** then my `$current_date_week` should bring back **20140330** and so on.

**This month** should do the same, get the last day of the current month in `Ymd` format and **next month** should get the last day of the next month.

I hope this made sense.

```
$current_date_week
$current_date_month
$current_date_month_next
```

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way:

```
$current_date_week  = date('Ymd', strtotime('this Sunday')); //20140330
$current_date_month = date('Ymd', strtotime('last day of this month'));//20140331
$next_date_month    = date('Ymd', strtotime('last day of next month'));//20140430
```

check available list for [formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use these as second arguments to date():

```
mktime(1,2,3,date('m'),date('d')+7-date('N'),date('Y'));
mktime(1,2,3,date('m')+1,0,date('Y'));
mktime(1,2,3,date('m')+2,0,date('Y'));
```